# Importing excel data to use with queries, not creating tables in Dbeaver MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, import, dbeaver

I have this giant random list of emails that this client wants set inactive in our system.  It's too big to do one by one and the users have no identifiers that make them group together, so I can't run some query to make them all inactive at once.

I want to import the excel data in Dbeaver so I can run an update query on each of those emails by connecting it to the email in the users database table.  Like a big loop of the excel email field.  But everything I see is just importing data into a table which is not what I want to do.

I suppose I could make a new table, import all the data, then write code linking the new table and the users table to do what I need, but it seems overkill and there should be a way to just use excel data for queries?

Is this possible or must I make a new table?

Comment: I ended up just importing all the data to a new table then just running queries against that table.  But if anyone knows a more direct way I am curious and will give you the upvote or answer for sure.

Comment: Mysql cannot directly link to excel files, only to delimited text files via its csv table engine. There is an excel odbc driver enabling applications to query excel sheets via sql statements, but that will not allow joins across other data sources. There are tools out there that can support mashing data from different data sources, but many of them will not allow modification of the data, just display.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  If you want to make that an answer I'll give it to you